# RxJava how to group items of one list to Map<Key, List<Value>>

Tags: kotlin, rx-java

I have a class "Cabinet" with such structure:

```
class Cabinet {
   var title: String
   var floor: Int
   var cabinetNumber: Int
}
```

And another class "Tabs"

```
class Tabs {
   var floor: Int
   var cabinetList: List<Cabinet>
}
```

So with help of RxJava I'm trying to create `Observable<List<Tabs>>`.
Firstly I get a List of Cabinet, so I have to get all "cabinets" to "Tabs" structure.

```
fun getCabinets(): Observable<List<Tabs>> {
   return getCabs()      //This metod returns List<Cabinet>
          .observeOn(Schedulers.io))
          .filter { it.title != null }
          ... ???  //There I don't get what to do next
```

I thought to use "toMap" to create collection `Map<floor: Int, cabinetList: List<Cabinet>>` but don't know how to make it reqursively. 
Please help

Comment: what do you finally convert into?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To put your cabinets into a `Map` you could utilize [`collectInto`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#collectInto-U-io.reactivex.functions.BiConsumer-) operator:

```
getCabs()
    .filter { it.title != null }
    .collectInto(mutableMapOf<Int, MutableList<Cabinet>>()) { map, cabinet ->
        if(map.contains(cabinet.floor)) map[cabinet.floor]?.add(cabinet)
        else map.put(cabinet.floor, mutableListOf(cabinet))
     }
     // here is your Map<Int, List<Cabinet>>
```

Going further, you could map your `Map` to `List<Tab>` using [`flatMapIterable`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#flatMapIterable-io.reactivex.functions.Function-) and `Set` of `Map` entries:

```
    .toObservable() // because collectInto returns Single
    .flatMapIterable { it.entries }
    .map { Tab(floor = it.key, cabinetList = it.value) }
    // here is your Observable<List<Tabs>>
```

P.S. I assume that you use `RxJava2`.